# Good way to represent collections of rectangles in sql

Tags: sql

This database holds schematical representations of physical bookshelves; here is an example :

[image: A shelf]

[image: Its schematical representation]

In the html5 canvas interface that allows users to create schematics, the shelves are simply represented as rectangles, so that our schematics top row could be

```
{ [0, 0, 66, 33], [67, 0, 33, 33] }
```

The properties of the desired SQL representation are pretty straightforward : user id, schematic id, shelf id. For example, the previous schematic could belong to user 1, be schematic 1, and hold shelves 1 to 8 going from left to right and top to bottom.

My best bet so far is to have a shelf table :

```
shelf [integer shelf_id, integer schematic_id, integer left, integer top, integer right, integer bottom]
```

And a schematic table :

```
schematic [integer schematic_id, integer user_id]
```

But it seems a little weird as a specific shelf belongs to one schematic and one only, and it demands a WHERE query to get all the shelves from a schematic. At the same time, should all the shelves be part of the schematic table, how would they exist as individual items with an individual id?

Is the scheme I propose the saner one for this scenario?

PS : would it be bad or indifferent to replace the top, right, bottom and left fields by one varchar "[left, top, right, bottom]" field to simplify insertions?

Comment: On your P.S.: Yes. Doing calculations would then always require to "decode" that string first. And checks on plausible data needed to be implemented as a `varchar` can hold all sorts of strings, not just `[l, t, r, b]`.

Comment: What's the DBMS you're using? Some already have geometric data types, which might be handy here.

Comment: Thank you for your first comment. As for your second comment, not a clue, this is a contribution I want to make to a project I am not yet part of; my guess is mysql.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to put the `schematic_id` on a shelf -- if you want shelves to be shared across different schemata.

You simply need a `schematic_shelf` association table with one row per schematic and one row per shelf in the schematic.

This would seem to better fit what you want to do.

Comment: nope, they absolutely must not be shared. They belong to one schematic only, even if another schematic has the very same shelf rectangle.